# Async/await seemingly not working

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I am not sure what is going on here. But I have a function which makes a simple API call using axios, all it does is return a string coming from the API call.

```
async function callSomeApi () {
  const res = await axios.get('http://someapi.com')
  console.log(res) // here I get the value I expected
  return res // this is going to be a simple string
}
```

That goes through as expected, the problem is when I call `callSomeApi` in another function. Things are running before

```
async function doSomething () {
  const someApiRes = await callSomeApi()
  console.log('I will be displayed before someApiRes is finished.')
  console.log(`someApiRes will be undefined: ${someApiRes}`)
}
```

Clearly I have some misunderstanding of async/await which I don't quite get. How do I fix my code?

Comment: All lines below the `await` do not run until the `await` resolves, sounds like things are as expected? If you wanted to have the `callSomeApi` come after the `console.log`s instead of before, just move the `await callSomeApi()` to below them.

Comment: That's how I thought it was, but in this case they seem to be running anyway before `await` has been resolved, which is why I am getting `undefined`. (Or at least that is my interpretation of it)

Comment: @robertotomás That won't do anything, async functions already automatically return promises.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/s38cvtyz/ - your code seems to work fine (with a dummy promise instead of axios.get) - so, unless `res` is **not** what you think it is, then the issue is not reproducible

Comment: hum... This is odd. Axios is indeed giving me the results I am expecting in my `console.log`. What is currently happening is just that everything else is running before it's done (so in this case my `callSomeApi` console.log is the last one to be displayed)

Comment: Can you repro your issue with an online sandbox? If not, then the issue lies in your particular arrangement of actual code.

Comment: I am trying as we speak, but I can't get axios to work with codepen for some reason.

Comment: Here's a fiddle using axios (and `res.statusText` instead of just `res`) http://jsfiddle.net/4y793hkr/

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. I guess there is something wrong with my code which hasn't been represented in my example. I am going to rethink this.

Comment: best practice is to right await inside try/catch block you will get to know if any occurs.

Comment: Yeah, I will be doing that from now on @RahulSharma. In this case it turned out to be my own stupidity.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and it turns out that it had nothing to do with `async/await`. Well... It did, but not in the way I thought it did. I am leaving this here in case someone else runs into the same thing and updating the OP accordingly.

In my example code for `someApiCall` I returned a string for the sake of simplicity. But in  reality I was returning an object which contained the string I wanted. SO think of `res` looking like this:

```
{
  myString: 'blah'
  somethingElse: 'blabla'
}
```

That is all lovely, but when it came time to use it in the `doSomething` call, I was actually doing this:

```
async function doSomething () {
  const someApiRes = await callSomeApi().myString // here is how it was actually being done
  console.log('I will be displayed before someApiRes is finished.')
  console.log(`someApiRes will be undefined: ${someApiRes}`)
}
```

I stupidly didn't realize that `await` wouldn't run my function and THEN access the `myString` property and it didn't even occur to me that that may have been a problem when writing my question.

So the solution for my problem was simply the following:

```
async function doSomething () {
  const someApiRes = await callSomeApi()
  const myString = someApiRes.myString()
  console.log('This is all working as expected.'))
}
```